# Helm can't pull image from local repo

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created a Docker image and is in my local repository like this:

```
docker build -t myimage:latest .
```

When I list my images I can see it just fine:

```
docker image ls --all
REPOSITORY                    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myimage                      latest    a91ac47487d4   28 minutes ago   370MB
```

Now I want to run this in Kubernetes, and here is my values.yaml image part:

```
image:
  repository: myimage
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: "latest"
```

I then try and install it:

```
helm install --generate-name .
```

And I can see it trying to start:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
default       chart-1631993007-buildchart-594448fddb-4prt4   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0              21s
```

I describe the pod:

```
kubectl describe pod chart-1631993007-buildchart-594448fddb-4prt4
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m3s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/chart-1631993007-buildchart-594448fddb-4prt4 to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    97s (x4 over 3m2s)  kubelet            Pulling image "myimage:latest"
  Warning  Failed     96s (x4 over 3m1s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "myimage:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed     96s (x4 over 3m1s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     68s (x6 over 3m)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    55s (x7 over 3m)    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "myimage:latest"
```

I understand that there is miss-naming somewhere,  either when i installed the image locally,  or how I am pulling it in my helm values.yaml,  But I just can't figure out where the miss-match is.

Any help would be great,  thank you.